# Firebase: How to get user uid with email only

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

How to generate a unique firebase user uid with just an email? Cannot use anonymous auth cause it changes the current auth user to the new created user uid. Ideally just want a function I can pass an email and generate a unique firebase user id for that email.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for Anonymous Authentication, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary
>   anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. These temporary
>   anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed
>   up to your app to work with data protected by security rules. If an
>   anonymous user decides to sign up to your app, you can link their
>   sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue
>   to work with their protected data in future sessions.

Comment: this will replace the current auth user to the anonymous one.